# Change domain's property during save in grails 2.3

Tags: grails

I am trying to modify or add a domain property during save action of a controller. I am using grails 2.3.2 and my code is as follows :

```
@Transactional
def save(Stock stockInstance) {
    if (stockInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }
    stockInstance.stockBy = User.findById(springSecurityService.getPrincipal().id)

    if (stockInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond stockInstance.errors, view: 'create'
        return
    }

    stockInstance.save flush: true

    request.withFormat {
        form {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'stockInstance.label', default: 'Stock'), stockInstance.id])
            redirect stockInstance
        }
        '*' { respond stockInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

The problem is, 'stockBy' property is comming up null. The springsecurityservice is returning a value but it is not being set in the property stockBy. This code worked fine in older versions of grails. Why is this not working for grails 2.3.2 ?

Comment: You code should work. Are you using GGTS or another IDE in your development? You could debug to make sure that `User.findById` is returning what you expect. Normally I tend to use `springSecurityService.currentUser`

Comment: I did println just after I assigned the stockBy for 'stockInstance.stockBy', 'springSecurityService.getPrincipal().id' and 'User.findById(springSecurityService.getPrincipal().id)' and I am getting all the correct results. The problem is, this result is not being persisted to the domain while validation, so I get error that 'stockBy' cannot be null.

Comment: Post your domain class code, are you using validators?

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled with the same issue. The problem is that the domain object remembers the previous errors and needs to be re-validated after adding the User to stockInstance.stockBy:

```
   stockInstance.stockBy = springSecurityService.currentUser
   stockInstance.validate()
```

Comment: That sounds right.  The original code is working with an instance that has already failed validation because Grails validates the command object before passing it into the action.  At that point the object is invalid so it has errors.  The code is then changing the state of the object and then calling .hasErrors().  hasErrors() is going to return true (and should) until the object has its errors cleared and/or is revalidated.